# How to put banner in css?

Tags: css, banner

How can I put an image as a banner, at the same time one more images as background? I don't know how to put the multiple image in css. I've trying to insert it, but one of the image is  missing when I browse it in the brwoser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<head>
            <style>
                        body {
                            background: url("img1.jpeg") ;
                        }
                        #banner {
                            position: absolute;
                            top: 0px;
                            left: 0px;
                            right: 0px;
                            width: 100%;
                            height: 200px;
                            z-index: -1;
                        }
            </style>
</head>
<body>
             <img id="banner" src="img2.jpeg" alt="Banner Image"/>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that @Tejas Patel has already answered your question. One thing which you mentioned in your question regarding "one or more images in the background", If I understand you correctly  you want to use One background with multiple images on it.If it is so then you can achieve that using CSS Sprites. You can play with it [here](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_image_sprites.asp)